# How to use .bind() in my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I have a function that is advancing scrolling images on a webpage. It can be seen here:

http://leadgenixhosting.com/~intmed/

The right arrow is what you click to advance the images. I have this problem where I have used .unbind() so that the arrow is unclickable until the images have finished with .animate() so that they don't get out of sync. But I'm not exactly sure how to use .bind() to make the arrow clickable again.

This is what the function currently looks like:

```
$('#in-right').click(
        function(){
            $('#in-right').unbind('click');
            imageSwitch();
            $('#in-right').bind('click');
        }
);
```

I'm obviously implementing bind incorrectly. How can I implement it right?

Here is my imageSwitch() function:

```
function imageSwitch(){

        current++;
        current_image++;
        previous_image++;
        next++;
        two_prev++

        if(two_prev >= divs.length){
            two_prev = 0;   
        }

        if(current >= gallery_images.length){
            current = 0;    
        }

        if(previous_image >= divs.length){
            previous_image = 0; 
        }

        if(current_image >= divs.length){
            current_image = 0;
        }

        if(next >= divs.length){
            next = 0;
        }   

        $('#'+divs[current_image]+'').animate({left:'-=1020px'},{queue:false,duration:1000})
        $('#'+divs[current_image]+'').css('background-image','url('+gallery_images[current]+')');

        $('#'+divs[previous_image]+'').animate({left:'-=1020px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});

        $('#'+divs[next]+'').animate({left: '+=1020px', top: '-=10000px'}, 1000);

        $('#'+divs[two_prev]+'').animate({left: '+=1020px', top: '+=10000px'}, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: You have to pass along a reference to the function you intend to bind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.bind` requires you pass it a function as the 2nd parameter.

```
function clickFunc(){  // Give the event function a name
    $('#in-right').unbind('click');
    imageSwitch();
    $('#in-right').click(clickFunc);  // .click is shorthand for `.bind('click',`
}
$('#in-right').click(clickFunc);
```

**EDIT**: You should make your `imageSwich` function take a callback, so it can re-bind the function once it's done animating.

```
function imageSwitch(callback){
    // code...
}

function clickFunc(){  // Give the event function a name
    $('#in-right').unbind('click');
    imageSwitch(function(){
        $('#in-right').click(clickFunc);
    });
}
$('#in-right').click(clickFunc);
```

As for making sure the callback runs once all the animations are done, we can use jQuery's [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Basically, you want to save the objects returned from `.animate` into varibles.  Then use `$.when`, and `.then` to run the callback at the correct time.

(This is untested, BTW)

```
function imageSwitch(callback) {
    var animations = [];

    current++;
    current_image++;
    previous_image++;
    next++;
    two_prev++

    if (two_prev >= divs.length) {
        two_prev = 0;
    }

    if (current >= gallery_images.length) {
        current = 0;
    }

    if (previous_image >= divs.length) {
        previous_image = 0;
    }

    if (current_image >= divs.length) {
        current_image = 0;
    }

    if (next >= divs.length) {
        next = 0;
    }

    animations.push($('#' + divs[current_image] + '').animate({
        left: '-=1020px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 1000
    }));

    $('#' + divs[current_image] + '').css('background-image', 'url(' + gallery_images[current] + ')');

    animations.push($('#' + divs[previous_image] + '').animate({
        left: '-=1020px'
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 1000
    }));

    animations.push($('#' + divs[next] + '').animate({
        left: '+=1020px',
        top: '-=10000px'
    }, 1000));

    animations.push($('#' + divs[two_prev] + '').animate({
        left: '+=1020px',
        top: '+=10000px'
    }, 1000));

    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        // Apply is used here because `$.when` expects to passed multiple parameters
        $.when.apply($,animations).then(callback);
    }
}
```

Deferred and animations demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M58KK/

Comment: When I use this, I run into the same problem I had before using .unbind(). When you click on the arrow halfway through .animate(), all the images get out of sync

Comment: @honestinjun: What does your `imageSwitch` function look like?  You need to have that re-bind the event instead (pass it a callback possibly).

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the function. I'll look into that

Comment: @honestinjun: Take a look my answer now, I think that should work.

Comment: That was fantastic! Works perfectly! I really appreciate that! I'd +10 that if I could.

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm still learning jQuery deferreds, so I figured I'd try it out here :-P